# Difference in ember output based on environment

Tags: javascript, ember.js

When running the ember build command

```
ember build --environment={testing or development or production or server}
```

Is there any difference in the actual dist output generated ? Can the same output be used across different envs?

I am aware about development having better error messages for debugging and similar differences...But wanted to know the exact differences if any e.g. base path in generated index.html or anything which can prevent them from being inter-operable across envs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference:

- The development output is not minified and contains source maps.
- The production output is minified fingerprinted. All `assert` calls from `@ember/debug` are removed.

Also different addons may do different things for production and development. One good example is [`ember-test-selectors`](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-test-selectors).

Besides that all code *should* work pretty much the same way. So nothing prevents you from running your development build in production or the other way around.

Comment: Can you add some information on `config/targets.js` which is generally different for production and dev environments and will results in drastically different builds if, for example, II11 is included for production?